# Why can I not change xorg.conf.d "OutputClass" to "Device" for RX560 GPU

Tags: linux, amd-graphics, graphic-card

I have a:

Lenovo Y520-15KIBA *CPU Intel i5* 
with GPU AMD Radeon RX560

linux kernel 4.20.47-custom (with bloobs of new firmware 1.175) DRM is 3.27.0

also kernel 4.17-generic is in the grub

I want to know how and if it is possible to setup a 10-amdgpu.conf file in a manner that my amdgpu is not showing errors like or at least give some glxgears output better than 1 FPS:

> dmesg | grep amdgpu

```
[    1.558902] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    1.559324] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    1.598721] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 2048M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F47FFFFFFF (2048M used)
[    1.598724] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GART: 256M 0x000000FF00000000 - 0x000000FF0FFFFFFF
[    1.598959] [drm] amdgpu: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    1.598961] [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
[    1.677073] [drm:dc_create [amdgpu]] *ERROR* DC: Number of connectors is zero!
[    1.923112] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.27.0 20150101 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   12.285945] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GPU pci config reset
```

> DRI_PRIME=0 | grep -B

```
Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2)  (0x591b)
Version: 18.2.8
```

> DRI_PRIME=1 | grep -B

```
Vendor: X.Org (0x1002)
Device: Radeon RX 560 Series (POLARIS11, DRM 3.27.0, 4.20.17-custom, LLVM 7
```

Testing my card with

> DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears

gives me 0.7 (sic!) frames per second and causes system freeze

therefore I think the card is not working properly

i have tried 2019 April with:

- drivers from amd ./amdgpu-install + pro on LMDE3, Linux Mint 19 ubuntu 18.04.1 18.04.2 (amd version 17.40, 18.x and 19.10) (each fresh install)
- mesa ppa oibaf Mint 19 Ubunut 18
- mesa ppa miguel Mint 19 (install failed) and Ubuntu 18
- somehow I was able to run mesa 19 on ubuntu 18 did not make a difference in glxgears
- custom kernel build 4.20. 5.0.6 5.0.8 5.0.9 LMDE3
- rocm on linux mint19 -I always did a video group  usermod *see below
- I tried various xorg.confs
- various vulkan installs and mesa-opencl-icd

*

> sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME

The standard configuration looks like:

> sudo pico /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "AMDgpu"
    MatchDriver "amdgpu"
    Driver "amdgpu"
EndSection
```

and is working out.

```
Section "Device"
```

is not working out (gives a black screen) and I want to know why. I hope to get better performance, when using **"Device"** and adding it to **"Screen Section"**

Comment: sources: [askubuntu-which-driver-should-i-use-for-my-rx-560-for-game](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967357/which-driver-should-i-use-for-my-rx-560-for-gaming) --- [LMDE2-amdgpu-kernel-build](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=266999)
---
[linux-arch_amdgpu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU)

Comment: I want to use shipped driver since [askubuntu-which-driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967357/which-driver-should-i-use-for-my-rx-560-for-gaming) this post. therefore I am looking for a setting for xorg.

Comment: source: [xorg-conf](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

long story short: Updating to linux mint 20 Ulyana (cinnamon) helped me out of my misery.

> dmesg|grep amdgpu

[    0.905200] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    0.905639] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 0: 0x90000000 -> 0x9fffffff
[    0.905642] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 2: 0xa0000000 -> 0xa01fffff
[    0.905644] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 5: 0xa2400000 -> 0xa243ffff
[    0.905653] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    0.940761] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: VRAM:2048M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F47FFFFFFF (2048M)
[    0.940764] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GART: 256M 0x000000FF00000000 - 0x000000FF0FFFFFFF
[    0.941049] [drm] amdgpu: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    0.941052] [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
[    0.943880] amdgpu: [powerplay] hwmgr_sw_init smu backed is polaris10_smu
[    1.277116] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.35.0 20150101 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   11.618382] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GPU pci config reset

> DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears

gives me 60 FPS as is my monitor refresh rate. Which tells me it is working fine now.

Comment: Case closed with linux mint update.

Comment: mesa works fine as well